# ModelForm field not showing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I know this is very simple but I've been at this for longer it should be and cannot find what I did wrong here.

I have a modelform where I want to include the primary key, and the name:

```
class ModbusDevice(models.Model):
    ixModbusDevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sModbusName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Device Name',max_length=100)

class BACnetModbusDeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModbusDevice
        fields = ['ixModbusDevice', 'sModbusName']
        widgets = {
                'ixModbusDevice' : TextInput(),
                'sModbusName' : TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            }
```

then in my view I have:
(BACnetModbusContainer is a custom class)

```
class BACnetModbusContainer:
    modbus_devices = None
    bacnet_devices = None
```

method:

```
modbus_devices = ModbusDevice.objects.all()

devices = []

for idx,device in enumerate(modbus_devices):
    container = BACnetModbusContainer()
    container.bacnet_devices = BACnetDeviceForm(prefix="bacnet_" + str(idx))
    container.modbus_devices = BACnetModbusDeviceForm(instance=device, prefix="modbus_" + str(idx))
    devices.append(container)

return render(
    request,
    'app/create_bacnet.html',
    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'Create BACnet Device',
        'tag': 'create_bacnet',
        'devices': devices
    })
)
```

then in my template:

```
{% for device in devices %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ device.modbus_devices.sModbusName }}
            {{ device.modbus_devices.ixModbusDevice }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Why is my `ixModbusDevice` not showing?

Comment: the sModbusName is showing?

Comment: yes the sModbusName is showing

Comment: when i add another field to the model and the form then it also shows, it jsut won't show the `ixModbusDevice` field(pk)

Comment: if you use {{device.modbus_devices}} what shows?

Comment: only the `sModbusName` field since that and `ixModbusDevice` are the only defined fields in my form. Pretty much all I want is to show the primary key. curse django!

Comment: seems in my template I cna access the primary key via the `initial` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to skip the rendering. I'm able to access the primary key via the "inital" attribute when I'm iterating all the devices:

```
{{ device.modbus_devices.initial.ixModbusDevice }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an AutoField. Your can't set those; they are automatically assigned by the database, hence the name. Therefore there's no point in showing then on the form.

Comment: i figured it had something to do with that. I just wasn't sure about how i'd go about linking the fields to the id, i didn't need to display it(was for testing hence why trying to display) but I had to find a place to put it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. I think the basic problem is that you are trying to show multiple forms on the page, but that way to do that in Django is to use a formset. That takes care of identifying which row is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the `return` to :

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/create_bacnet.html',
    {
         'title':'Create BACnetDevice',
         'tag':'create_bacnet',
         'devices': devices
    }
)
```

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

[Render Shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Comment: still doesn't work. Is it because I'm trying to display a primary key? (initally had it as HiddenField() but wasn't generating so changed it to be visiable for testing)